# Why does Dumbledore see Grindelwald in the Mirror of Erised?

Tags: plot-explanation, fantastic-beasts, the-crimes-of-grindelwald

In the newly released *Fantastic Beasts: Crimes of Grindelwald* movie, we find a scene where Professor Dumbledore sees Gellert Grindelwald in the Mirror of Erised. Now, this doesn't seem to make sense because in the *Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows* book we find Professor Dumbledore had seen his sister back alive in the Mirror of Erised in Harry's first year.

Is this another mistake made by J.K. Rowling or is there any explanation for this?

Comment: Doesn't the Grinelwald story happen a long time before Harry's first year? What speaks against Dumbledore seeing something else than what he sees decades later? Was his sister already dead by the events of *Crimes of Grindelwald*?

Comment: @Napolean But what could have made him change that? Yeah, his sister was already dead by the events of this movie so shouldn't he see her?

Comment: @SuryaKantaBoseChowdhury lover/heart-break/family they can take any turn

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's just a change of heart. With time people get over a broken heart or at-least stop wishing to get it back.

That's what happens here; Dumbledore sees his lover in the mirror as he is still not over him and wish him back. But with time his wishes change and he sees his sister in the original film series.

With age and time, your priority and wishes change and Dumbledore is no different.

Even in *Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone*, Harry sees his parents first and later in the film he sees Philosopher's Stone.